# Loopback 3.x Transaction over two data sources

Tags: loopbackjs

I've used Higher-level Transaction API of Loopback, but it supports only one datasource, as you start the transaction with

```
await app.dataSources.db.transaction(async models => {});
```

I have two data sources pointing to two separate databases on the same mysql database server, and I would like to use write into two tables, each residing in separate database, in the same transaction. Is it possible to achieve it somehow in Loopback? Maybe using Lower-level Transaction API? Any experience?